# SQL sum select returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I want to obtain unread messages count from MySQL database using `SELECT SUM` operator.

So, my SQL is:

```
SELECT sum(status_field = 'new') unreadMessagesCount
FROM messages
WHERE 'author_uid' = 'authorUID'
```

And it returns `NULL`. **Why?**

I have items in database and I can select it by (`SELECT * FROM messages`)

Comment: you have items with `status_field = new` ?

Comment: `'author_uid' = 'authorUID'` is always false, so no rows will be selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns `NULL` because you are comparing *strings*, not *columns* with:

```
WHERE 'author_uid' = 'authorUID'
```

And these two strings are not equal.  So, all rows are filtered out.  The `NULL` value is because you have an aggregation query.  `SUM()` returns `NULL` when there are no rows in such a query.

I'm not sure what you intend.  Perhaps:

```
WHERE author_uid = 'authorUID'
```

However, `'authorUID'` seems like a strange value for a `uid`.  You need to put an appropriate value there.  If it is a string, enclose it in single quotes.  If it is a number, do not use single quotes.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot! You are right, I compared two strings instead of column with specified value!